# Android Fragment Confusion

Tags: android, fragment

I have a question about the correct logical use of fragments in Android. I know that it was designed to be used to improve tablet experience, but does this imply that fragments should generally ONLY be used for this purpose? Or would it be poor development practice to use fragments as a replacement for a custom compound View?

For example, I am writing an app to keep tally. When the score sheet is produced, it creates a "ScoreCell," a custom compound control, for each player in a ScrollView. What I want to do(but don't see how as a View) is handle internal OnClickListeners that are activated by the containing activity: each ScoreCell has a TextView for the players' name, which I want to long-press to startActivityForResult() to pop open an input dialog to change the name of the ScoreCell. But seeing as the method for OnActivityResult() is unavailable in a View, would it be correct for me to instead make each ScoreCell a fragment?

[Here is a picture of the activity to help understand the logic of what I need/am confused about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnT9O.png)

Comment: I think this image says most of how Fragments were intended to be used. http://developer.android.com/images/fundamentals/fragments.png . Sometimes it makes complete sense to have an Activity in which there is only one fragment.

Comment: No don't make score cell a fragment. As far as name changing is concerned, use a `DialogFragment` for that purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many questions in here, let me go through them.

1. No fragments are not meant just for tablet experience, in general they allow you to create more modular and adaptable layouts (think classes). They are extremely helpful in tablet layouts/landscape, but also give you reusable components.
2. At the same time, a fragment is not the right choice here... It is much easier to use a listview, coupled with a custom cell layout. Instead of using another activity to display a dialog simply call new Dialog() and dialog.show(). An activity should only be used as a dialog if it will be used by the user by a long period of time and provides a new "activity" (action)

Answer (score 1):

Items in a list should not each be their own fragment, no. You can pop up a dialog without creating an entire Activity. Take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) on AlertDialogs and DialogFragments for your dialogs and you can get the result from that.